# getting karma error when trying to inject firebase in angularjs module

Tags: angularjs, firebase, karma-runner

This is my module:

```
// app.module.js
angular.module('app', ['firebase']);
```

I have configured karma like this:

```
// karma.conf.js
files: [
  'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
  'bower_components/firebase/firebase.js',
  'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  'src/**/*.js'
],
```

This is my test:

```
// data.service.spec.js
describe('dataservice', function () {

var dataservice;

beforeEach(module('app'));

beforeEach(function () {
    inject(function (_dataservice_) {
        dataservice = _dataservice_;
    });
});

describe('getData()', function () {

    it('should return an object', function () {
        expect(typeof dataservice.getData()).to.equal('object');
    });

});
```

});

After "karma start --log-level DEBUG" I'm getting error:

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) dataservice "before each" hook for "should return an object" FAILED
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module fire/home/me/Documents/web/my-app due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module 'fire/home/me/Documents/web/my-app' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

Test is green if I remove firebase injection in the app.module.js

What am I doing wrong here????

Comment: Looks like something is converting "base" in "firebase" to the absolute path to your webapp. Weird. Care to add the rest of your `karma.conf.js`, specifically any plugins / pre-processors

Comment: I've included entire karma.conf.js,

Comment: You sure you don't accidentally have `"fireD:/Documents/web/app"` in any of your files?

Comment: Yes I'm sure I don't.

Comment: @Phil you're right and it's actually a bug in karma, one that will really mess with your head :-) See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just got unlucky.

The reason you get a very odd message is because of a bug in some versions of karma where it replaces the string "base" with {whatever your base is} when printing output to the reporter (see this [issue](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/1706))

So angular throws this error:

```
 module firebase
```

But karma prints this:

```
 module fireD:/Documents/web/app
```

Which confuses the hell out of you!

The reason you get that error is because you also need to load angularfire:

```
'bower_components/firease/firebase.js',
'bower_components/angularfire/dist/angularfire.js
```

(And you have misspelled **firebase** as **firease**)

I recommend you update karma to the latest version (although that bug apparently crept back in at some stage)

By the way, Karma usually isn't very good at telling you when it doesn't find files, but you can run it with a higher log level and it tells you where it's actually looking for files:

```
karma start --log-level DEBUG
```

Comment: I'm using the latest 0.13.21 version of karma and correcting misspelling didn't fix the problem, but it's now obvious that the issue is due to karma bug. I'll check the issue and come back, hopefully with the fix. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I went and tested it all and found what the problem was. See updated answer. Bower firebase is for firebase itself, not the angular component.

Comment: @AndyHaslt Thanks a loooooooot!!!! Installing and including angularfire to karma.conf.js did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The error/exception is raised by Angular, so please check whether you have referenced `firebase.js` in your webapp, not just `karma.conf.js`'s `files` section.

Comment: Could you give me an example where to reference it?

Comment: Because I'm instansiating new Firebase in a dataservice and it works fine in the app, it just raises error in karma test runner and I cannot do testing because of it.

Comment: You may want to put <script href="... firebase. js" /> in the file where you reference angular.js

Comment: No it doesn't work! I'm still getting the same error.